How can I use `file://` to get tiles from folders z/x/y on Android in a maplibre-native (mapboxSdk)?
I'm trying to add a raster layer to a map via RasterLayer(id, uri)
and pass the uri as
"file://"+LocalContext.current.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.path+"/tiles.json" 
Inside tiles.json there is information about the boundaries and zoom levels, as well as the path to the tiles:

"tiles": ["file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/project.name/files/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"]

But for some reason mapLibre does not get tiles from there. The only way out is to add a local server, but i would like to avoid it if possible and transfer the tiles directly.
